# How do I make div border to be flex but have minimum height?

Tags: html, css

StackOverflow.

I would like for the divs border where the information pane and tables are to have minimum height and also flex height when table content get out of the border.

Example:
[link 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDgjt.png)
[link 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yF5dO.png)
Note: StackOverflow does not allow me to post picures yet as I am a new to the developers world. Please use the links provides. Thank you.

Html code:

```
<div class="searchAndTablesContainer">
<!--    Left panel-->
  <div class="searchPanel">
        Informational pane
      <input class="button1 button2" type="submit" value="Get All Users" onclick="getAllUsers()">
      <input class="button1 button2" type="submit" value="Get All Shop Services" onclick="getAllShopServices()">
  </div>
<!--    Right Panel-->
    <div class="tablesPanel">
            <div id="passReset" style="display:block">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <tr class="bg-info" style="text-align: center">
                        <th data-column="id" data-order="desc">Request ID &#9660</th>
                        <th data-column="account_email" data-order="desc">Account Email &#9660</th>
                        <th data-column="date_requested" data-order="desc">Date Requested &#9660</th>
                        <th data-column="date_restarted" data-order="desc">Date Restarted &#9660</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tbody id="passResetTable">
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        <div id="users" style="display:block">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tr class="bg-info" style="text-align: center">
                    <th data-column="id" data-order="desc">User ID &#9660</th>
                    <th data-column="first_name" data-order="desc">First Name &#9660</th>
                    <th data-column="last_name" data-order="desc">Last Name &#9660</th>
                    <th data-column="phone" data-order="desc">Phone&#9660</th>
                    <th data-column="email" data-order="desc">Email &#9660</th>
                    <th data-column="enabled" data-order="desc">Enabled &#9660</th>
                </tr>
                <tbody id="usersTable">
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="services" style="display:block">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tr class="bg-info" style="text-align: center">
                    <th data-column="id" data-order="desc">Shop Service ID &#9660</th>
                    <th data-column="first_name" data-order="desc">Service Name &#9660</th>
                    <th data-column="last_name" data-order="desc">Service Price &#9660</th>
                </tr>
                <tbody id="shopServicesTable">
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.searchAndTablesContainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.searchPanel {
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    flex: auto;
    background-color: white;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    outline:1px solid black;
}

.tablesPanel {
    width: 68%;
    height: 100%;
    flex: auto;
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    outline:1px solid black;
}
```

I would be very grateful to anyone who helps me out with this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Add min-height to the css element you want a minimum height of?

Comment: It doesn't work when I add flex:atuo as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `display: flex` for the container (and of course `min-height`). So you can also get rid of "*float*":

```css
.searchAndTablesContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.searchPanel {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.tablesPanel {
  width: 68%;
  background-color: white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchAndTablesContainer">
  <!--    Left panel-->
  <div class="searchPanel">
    Informational pane
    <input class="button1 button2" type="submit" value="Get All Users" onclick="getAllUsers()">
    <input class="button1 button2" type="submit" value="Get All Shop Services" onclick="getAllShopServices()">
  </div>
  <!--    Right Panel-->
  <div class="tablesPanel">
    <div id="passReset" style="display:block">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr class="bg-info" style="text-align: center">
          <th data-column="id" data-order="desc">Request ID &#9660</th>
          <th data-column="account_email" data-order="desc">Account Email &#9660</th>
          <th data-column="date_requested" data-order="desc">Date Requested &#9660</th>
          <th data-column="date_restarted" data-order="desc">Date Restarted &#9660</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody id="passResetTable">
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <div id="users" style="display:block">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr class="bg-info" style="text-align: center">
          <th data-column="id" data-order="desc">User ID &#9660</th>
          <th data-column="first_name" data-order="desc">First Name &#9660</th>
          <th data-column="last_name" data-order="desc">Last Name &#9660</th>
          <th data-column="phone" data-order="desc">Phone&#9660</th>
          <th data-column="email" data-order="desc">Email &#9660</th>
          <th data-column="enabled" data-order="desc">Enabled &#9660</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody id="usersTable">
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="services" style="display:block">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr class="bg-info" style="text-align: center">
          <th data-column="id" data-order="desc">Shop Service ID &#9660</th>
          <th data-column="first_name" data-order="desc">Service Name &#9660</th>
          <th data-column="last_name" data-order="desc">Service Price &#9660</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody id="shopServicesTable">
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I just couldn't figure out the combination of styles. Was putting height in the sub divs etc. etc. Thank you.

Comment: If that answers your question then you should mark it as accepted...

Comment: Can't seem to be able to do that yet. As well as upvoting. I will once I am able.

Comment: Maybe that helps you https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers